# Unique stationary solution for AR(1)

Tags: time-series, econometrics, autoregressive

So I have a somewhat typical AR(1) process with the phi value being -1, i.e. $$ X_{t} = (-1) * X_{t-1} + Z_{t} $$

How do I go about showing that this covariance stationary process has a unique solution in the form of $$ X_{t} = (-1)^k * X_{t-1} $$

I've tried forward iteration and the solution I get to is that $$ X_{t} = (-1)^k * X_{t-k} $$ + a summation of white-noise error terms that we set to zero.

Comment: Why do you say that it's covariance stationary?

Comment: X(t) is defined as a covariance stationary process. I wasn't fully certain if it's a relevant part of the information or not.

Comment: But, it has a root on the unit circle. And in your second equation, $k$ doesn't have a meaning